# React Hook useEffect has a missing dependency: 'fetchData'

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-redux, react-hooks, webhooks

can anyone help me with this error? In **useEffect** I call a function that makes a request and inserts the response in a redux state.

```
import React, { useEffect, useState } from "react";
import { BrowserRouter as Router, Switch, Route} from "react-router-dom";
import { useDispatch, useSelector } from 'react-redux'
import { actions } from './actions/actions'
import { I18nProvider } from './i18n'
import axios from 'axios'

import Home from './views/home/home';
import Page1 from './views/page1/page1';
import Page2 from './views/page2/page2'
import Page3 from './views/page3/page3'

const App = () => {

  const [isLoading, setIsLoading] = useState(true)

  const localeDefault = useSelector(state => state.audioGuideReducers.lang)

  const dispatch = useDispatch()
  const setDataRedux= (data) => dispatch(actions.setDataRedux(data))

  useEffect(() => {
    fetchData();
  }, []);

  const fetchData = async () => {
    await axios.get('https://link-api.com/alldata')
      .then((response) => {
        setDataRedux(response.data.data)
        setIsLoading(false)
      })
      .catch( (error) => {
        console.log(error.message);
      })
  }

  return (
    <I18nProvider locale={localeDefault}>
      <Router>
        {
          isLoading ?
            <h1> Loading... </h1>
            :
            <Switch>
              <Route path="/page3/:id" component={Page3} />
              <Route path="/page2" component={Page2} />
              <Route path="/page1" component={Page1} />
              <Route path="/" component={Home} />
            </Switch>
        }
      </Router>
    </I18nProvider>
  );
}

export default App
```

Although the application is "running", I would like to resolve the following warning that appears:
"*React Hook useEffect has a missing dependency: 'fetchData'. Include it or remove the dependency matrix react-hooks/exaustive-deps*"

Comment: if answer(https://stackoverflow.com/a/64025959/6544460) is helpful for you, please accept/vote for this... Happy coding!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Its because whenever you are using `useEffect` and if you use something that is outside from useEffect. UseEffect need to make sure when to update when not that's why you need to pass it in its dependency:

```
useEffect(() => {
    fetchData();
  }, [fetchData]);

  const fetchData = async () => {
    await axios.get('https://link-api.com/alldata')
      .then((response) => {
        setDataRedux(response.data.data)
        setIsLoading(false)
      })
      .catch( (error) => {
        console.log(error.message);
      })
  }
```

Better way if you need only inside `useEffect` put `fetchData` inside `useEffect`:

```
const setDataRedux = React.useCallback((data) => dispatch(actions.setDataRedux(data)), [])
useEffect(() => {
    const fetchData = async () => {
    await axios.get('https://link-api.com/alldata')
      .then((response) => {
        setDataRedux(response.data.data)
        setIsLoading(false)
      })
      .catch( (error) => {
        console.log(error.message);
      })
  }
    fetchData();
  }, [setDataRedux]);
```

Comment: Ahh thanks . We dont required `fetchData` as dependency

Comment: Hello, first of all, thank you very much for your help.
I implemented the second path, inserting fetchData () inside useEffect (), but the warning persists, now like this:
"React Hook useEffect has a missing dependency: 'setDataAudioguide'. Either include it or remove the dependency array"

Comment: And if I put the setDataAudioguide in the useEffect dependencies the message is as follows: The 'setDataAudioguide' function makes the dependencies of useEffect Hook (at line 66) change on every render. Move it inside the useEffect callback. Alternatively, wrap the 'setDataAudioguide' definition into its own useCallback () Hook

Comment: Ahh you need to pass it if you are using second method. I didn't consider `setDataAudioGuide`. Genereally you dont need if its `setData` from `useState` one. I have updated my answer plz check again

Comment: Great. If this works for you. Plz accept and vote this answer. It helps other if someone stuck on same type problem

Answer (score 1):

Pass `fetchData` as an argument to `useEffect`

```
 useEffect(() => {
    fetchData();
  }, [fetchData]);
```